# Does a "use" statement persist through includes?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

Best explained with an example:

**file1.php**

```
<?php

use Vendor\Module\Class as MyClass;

MyClass::$something = TRUE;

?>
```

**file2.php**

```
<?php

require file1.php;

echo MyClass::$something;

?>
```

Ok so I admit that I already tried it and get a "class not found" error but I refuse to believe that this is not possible? Is there some way of accomplishing this? Is it already possible and I'm making a ridiculous typo?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to know the answer, so what is the question, really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this note on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-296) page:

> Note:
>   Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.